# Efficient time bound queue in Python?

Tags: python, caching, data-structures, stream, queue

What would be an efficient approach to replicate `pandas` rolling window functionality on live streaming data?

Suppose we want to maintain a sum of last *n* observations, `collections.deque` with `maxlen` parameter is the way to go, but what if instead of a fixed *n* we need a sum of values from last *m* seconds?

Using `pandas.Series` would be inefficient since the underlying `numpy` arrays are immutable and thus unsuitable for handling live data streams - each append copies the whole array.

Something like `cachetools.TTLCache` is good for storing the live data, but inefficient for calculations - getting the sum would require to iterate over each element every time.

Currently my approach for maintaining a live data stream sum uses `collections.deque`, *time-to-live* parameter and a `while` loop for discarding old values:

```
import time
from collections import deque

class Accumulator:
    def __init__(self, ttl):
        self.ttl = ttl
        self.sum = 0
        self.q = deque()

    def append(self, value):
        self.q.append((time.time(), value))
        self.sum += value
        self.discard_old_values()

    def discard_old_values(self):
        cutoff_time = time.time() - self.ttl
        try:
            while self.q[0][0] < cutoff_time:
                self.sum -= self.q.popleft()[1]
        except IndexError:
            pass

    def get_sum(self):
        self.discard_old_values()
        return self.sum
```

So the questions are:

1. Can we do better?
2. Is there a way to get rid of the ugly `while` loop here?
3. What's the common name for this type of "TTL queue" data structure?
4. Is there a popular Python library that already implements it?
5. Is there a way to utilize `pandas` rolling windows on mutable collections?

Comment: This implementation is pretty good for what it does.  Does it satisfy your requirements, or do you mean something else by "we need a sum of values from last m seconds"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proposed improvement to `discard_old_values`:

```
def discard_old_values(self):
    die = time.time() - self.ttl
    while(len(self.q) > 0 and self.q[0][0] < die):
        self.sum -= self.q.popleft()[1]
```

I decided to, instead of call `time.time()` for each element that may be discarded, call it once and do the arithmetic to find the "die time" only once.

This saves the cost of throwing exceptions, and the cost of multiple calls to time.

Comment: Good point on moving `time.time()` call outside of the while loop. Edited the original post to reflect that. Not so sure about adding `len(self.q) > 0` (which can be shortened to simply `self.q`) check for each element. I think catching `IndexError` just once should be faster.